# RxJs 6 - Make 2 http calls and wait for all responses

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects, fork-join, rxjs6

```
@Effect()    
initDomain$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType('INIT_DOMAIN'),
  mergeMap((action: any) =>
     this.http.get('https://demo.api/url1.php').pipe(
        switchMap((data) => [
           {type: 'INIT_IT', payload: data}
        ]),
        catchError(() => of({type: 'INIT_IT_FAILED'}))
     )
  )
);
```

I have this angular effect (ngrx) that makes 1 request before continue. How can I make 2 requests and wait for both responses before continue? I know that forkJoin() is the answer but I'm little confused about the syntax

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: https://gist.github.com/peterbsmith2/ce94c0a5ddceb99bab24a761731d1f07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
forkJoin(
 this.http.get('myUrl'),
 this.http.get('myOtherUrl')
)
```

OR if you have a bundle of observables in an array you could also write

```
const myArrayOfObservables = [
  this.http.get('myUrl'),
  this.http.get('myOtherUrl')
];

forkJoin(
  myArrayOfObservables
)
```

This is because "forkJoin" uses the "spread" (...args) operator for its params.

Comment: Note that the whole obs will be considered as failed if one of them failed when using forkJoin whereas some calls might have succeeded.